# Regex match if certain string is contained after last occurrence of specific character

Tags: regex

For example, I want to check if the web url contains 'foo' after last slash, and match the entire url. So the following url should be a match:

- https://www.facebook.com/messages/new/foobar
- https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/barfoo
- https://www.facebook.com/bfooar
- https://foobar.com
- https://foobar.com/foo

But the following shouldn't:

- https://random.com/random
- https://foobar.com/something
- https://foobar.com/foo/bar

My approach is `((\\.*)*\\.*foo.*)`, but it seems doesn't work for any url that contains foo before the last slash. Is this pattern even doable in regex? Or I have to use something like split('\') in the code to achieve the desired pattern I want?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have ``\\`` in the pattern if you have `/` in the URLs? What is the environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^.*/[^/]*foo[^/]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Jy5O0/1)

**Breakup:**

- `^` - Start
- `.*` - Match 0 or more characters (greedy)
- `/` - Match a `/`
- `[^/]*` - Match 0 or more non-`/` characters
- `foo` - match `foo`
- `[^/]*` - Match 0 or more non-`/` characters
- `$` - End